# Entity Framework Foreign Key to a Non Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and need to set up a foreign key from one table to another in an Oracle database. But, the key in the other table is not the table's primary key. Here are snippets of my models:

```
[Table("X_METER_USE")]
public partial class XMeterUse
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Column("PROJECT")]
    public string Project { get; set; }

    //... some more columns in here

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Column("ID_NUMBER")]
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }
}

[Table("STANDARD_REAGENT")]
public partial class StandardReagent
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(80)]
    [Column("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

        //... some more columns here 

    [Column("SAMPLE_NUMBER")]
    public int? SampleNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So, in this case, `IdNumber` from `XMeterUse` is a foreign key to `StandardReagent`, but it corresponds to `SampleNumber`, not the primary key `Name`.

The relationship in this case is many to one, in the sense that the `StandardReagent` can have many `XMeterUses`, but each `XMeterUse` can optionally have only one `StandardReagent`, the two tables linked by `IdNumber--SampleNumber`.

`XMeterUse` has the data I need to display on screen, where I also need two columns from `StandardReagent`. I've researched and found some answers, and while similar, they are not quite the situation I have here. A colleague recommended I use the fluent API to achieve this, but I still need a push in the right direction on how to set this up. I think the best solution would be to re-architect the tables to not be linked like this, but I don't have this option, the database is already established and used by other applications. Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to update to .NET Core to have this feature.

Comment: EF6 - no way. EF Core - possible in general, but not when the type of the columns differ as in your case.